# How to style text passed from iteration in leaflet map pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a list of points in which I want to iterate and add to leaflet map. I am able to add the points to the maps but when I try to style the text using **h1 tags**, the style is not applied text from the iteration. From leaflet tutorials I can see that the text in pop up can be styled with header tags. How can i style this text which i am passing to the pop up window through iteration. Below is my sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <title>TestMap</title>
</head>
<style>
    #map{height : 100vh;}
</style>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
</body>
<script>
var locations = [
    ["Point 1", 61, 23],
    ["Point 2", 62, 21],
  ];

var map = L.map('map').setView([ 63,27], 5.5);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    for (let loc of locations){
        //  console.log(loc[0])
        marker = new L.marker([loc[1], loc[2]])
        .bindPopup("<h1> loc[0] </h1> ")
        .addTo(map);
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML tags within the bindPopup method.
For example:

```
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var point = L.marker([location[1], location[2]]).addTo(map);
  point.bindPopup(`<h1>${location[0]}</h1>`);
});
```

This will add an h1 element around the location name within the popup.

For styling  h1 element using CSS:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I guess its the way i did the iteration that affects it. I changed the iteration part and it worked even without the css.  Now i remember with the forEach you can pass a function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74983276/how-to-style-text-passed-from-iteration-in-leaflet-map-pop-up-window/74983392#74983392) provided by [@divyavinod6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20846675/divyavinod6), I changed the ***for*** to **forEach** to perform the iteration. The **forEach** allows running function on the iteration element. below is the full code if it will be useful for someone else

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="customstyle.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"

     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <title>TestMap</title>
</head>
<style>
    #map{height : 100vh;}
</style>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
</body>
<script>
var locations = [
    ["Point 1", 61, 23],
    ["Point 2", 62, 21],
  ];

var map = L.map('map').setView([ 63,27], 5.5);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

locations.forEach(function(location) {
    var point = L.marker([location[1], location[2]]).addTo(map);
    point.bindPopup(`<h1>${location[0]}</h1>`);
});

</script>
</html>
```